# Высокий показатель правильности ответов модели нейронной сети

Tags: python, tensorflow

У меня есть нейронная сеть

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, activation="relu", input_shape=(5, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(30, activation="relu", input_shape=(5, )))
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(30,)))

# Компиляция модели
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

# Обучение модели
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=20, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

metrics = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
metrics
```

Я обучил ее и протестировал. Но есть момент который меня тревожит, а именно, эти показатели на тестовой выборке.

```
Validation loss: 0.03399088233709335
Validation mean absolute error: 0.13117270171642303
Validation accuracy:  99.9660091176629
```

Являются ли они правильными и не говорит о переобучении

Answer (score 1):

```py
validation_data=(X_test, y_test)
```

Вот это неправильный подход. Как минимум, для валидации должны быть отдельные данные, не те же самые, что для теста (и трейна). Когда попробуете с отдельными данными, тогда можно будет дальше разговаривать, опираясь на метрики на тестовой выборке.

Хотя в общем случае, не зная решаемую вами задачу, природу ваших данных и то, как вы их поделили по трейну/валидации/тесту, довольно сложно сказать, является ли точность почти 100% нормой для этой задачи или нет. В общем случае такого не должно быть, но данные бывают разные.

Если бы это была не нейросеть, а более простая модель, то я бы сказал, что точность на тесте около 100% однозначно свидетельствует об "утечке данных" (а не о переобучении). Что мы тут, кажется, и наблюдаем.

P.S. Вот если метрики точности на трейне (и, возможно, валидации тоже) будут под 100%, а на тесте скажем 80%, то это будет переобучение. Если приведённые вами метрики относятся таки к валидации, а не к тесту, то тогда это может быть переобучение, а не утечка данных, но сказать точно можно будет только когда вы покажете все метрики: и на трейне и на валидации и на тесте.

Comment: validation_data=(X_test, y_test) на этих данные просто происходит вычисление loss (так указано в документации) На этих данных модель не обучается.

Comment: Я взял похожие данные, но модель все равно выводит почти 100 %

Comment: Можно вставлю свои пять копеек? судя по архитектуре, это модель для решения задачи регрессии (на выходе 1 нейрон без функции активации). Метрика точности accuracy считается для задачи классификации. Здесь что-то не так. Если Вам кажется результат слишком высоким... судя по тому, что вы используете слой LSTM, у Вас какие-то временные данные? Такие данные на трейн и тест нельзя делить перемешиванием, а нужно делить на "до" и "после". Могли ли Вы допустить такую ошибку?

Comment: @НиколайБруцкий-Стемпковский
У меня есть набор данных и я хочу предсказать за какое время произойдет определенное событие. Могли бы вы подсказать, как мне лучше поступить. И какую метрику точности взять для моей задачи

Comment: ну судя по всему, Вам подойдут метрики mae, mse (rmse) - те, которые оценивают насколько близко вы предсказали величину, а не попали/не попали в класс. А что представляют собой данные? можно подробнее, пожалуйста? Сколько предсказывающих переменных? целевая переменная как с ними связана? данные наверное отсортированы хронологически?

Comment: @НиколайБруцкий-Стемпковский
В общем. У меня есть данные температура погоды, силы ветра, температура внутри здания и есть температура, которая указывал человек, что бы в комнате указанная температура. И я хочу предсказать, за сколько времени произойдет нагрев (или охлаждения комнаты), высчитывается по формуле. Я не совсем понимаю, как мне правильно все сделать, что бы все работало отлично

Comment: Формула https://postimg.cc/23jRwKDD

Comment: @НиколайБруцкий-Стемпковский Мы можем перейти в тг, если так разрешено правилом сообщества? Если мы сможем решить проблему, можно будет о ней написать здесь

Comment: Ну тогда здесь не нужны слои LSTM, у Вас не последовательность данных, а независимые объясняющие переменные. Слои LSTM используются для задач timeseries, когда зная хронологию событий, нужно предсказать будущее (например, зная температуру за 12 часов подряд, предсказать, что будет через час). у Вас вроде просто отдельные входные величины, а отдельные наблюдения не связаны друг с другом. Вообще странно, что Вы решили использовать нейросеть, когда у Вас уже есть готовая формула, ну да ладно... Ну в теории такое может быть наверное, что нейросеть "раскусила" эту формулу и под нее подстроилась

Comment: Ведь обычно к нейросетям прибегают, когда не могут выстроить связь между всеми входными данными и целевой переменной, потому что эти связи не так очевидны.

Comment: В ТГ не надо..)

Comment: @7wafer7 Да, я пожалуй неправ насчёт утечки данных из-за валидации. Надо разбираться в задаче подробнее. Она видимо в другом месте.

Comment: Друзья, насколько я знаю, нейросеть из всего трёх нейронов можно обучить логической функции XOR. Здесь мы имеем дело с чем-то похожим. Между всеми объяснящими переменными и выходом сети имеется вполне однозначная взаимосвязь, описанная формулой. Может просто имеет место тот факт, что сеть выучила эту связь на отлично и хорошо ее воспроизводит на тестовых данных?

Comment: @НиколайБруцкий-Стемпковский Скорее всего именно так. Но хорошо бы посмотреть всё же данные.

Comment: @НиколайБруцкий-Стемпковский 
Куда мне выложить дата сет, что бы вы могли взглянуть на него?